# How can I ignore background noise (low decibel sound) when using AudioUnits in iOS

Tags: ios, core-audio, accelerate-framework

I'm hacking together a simple app just now and I've been using two classes described in [this post by Kevin Murphy](http://kevmdev.com/tutorials/autocorrelation-frequency-estimation/)

My code works fine except that it picks up a lot of background noise - I'm only interested in picking up loud, nearby sounds from my guitar.

I have basically no experience of working with the Accelerate framework or any of the AudioUnit stuff.

Can anybody have a look into these classes by Kevin Murphy and tell me how I could modify them to ignore sounds below a certain decibel threshold?

```
/*
 Copyright (c) Kevin P Murphy June 2012

 Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

 The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

 THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
 */

#import "AudioController.h"

#define kOutputBus 0
#define kInputBus 1

@implementation AudioController
@synthesize rioUnit, audioFormat, delegate;


void checkStatus(OSStatus status);
void checkStatus(OSStatus status) {
    if(status!=0)
        printf("Error: %ld\n", status);
}

#pragma mark init

- (id)init
{
    OSStatus status;
    status = AudioSessionInitialize(NULL, NULL, NULL, (__bridge void*) self);
    checkStatus(status);

    // Describe audio component
    AudioComponentDescription desc;
    desc.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Output;
    desc.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO;
    desc.componentFlags = 0;
    desc.componentFlagsMask = 0;
    desc.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;

    // Get component
    AudioComponent inputComponent = AudioComponentFindNext(NULL, &desc);

    // Get audio units
    status = AudioComponentInstanceNew(inputComponent, &rioUnit);
    checkStatus(status);


    // Enable IO for recording
    UInt32 flag = 1;

    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(rioUnit,                                   
                                  kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO, 
                                  kAudioUnitScope_Input, 
                                  kInputBus,
                                  &flag,
                                  sizeof(flag));
    checkStatus(status);


    // Describe format
    audioFormat.mSampleRate= 44100.0;
    audioFormat.mFormatID= kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
    audioFormat.mFormatFlags= kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked;
    audioFormat.mFramesPerPacket= 1;
    audioFormat.mChannelsPerFrame= 1;
    audioFormat.mBitsPerChannel= 16;
    audioFormat.mBytesPerPacket= 2;
    audioFormat.mBytesPerFrame= 2;

    // Apply format
    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(rioUnit, 
                                  kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, 
                                  kAudioUnitScope_Output, 
                                  kInputBus, 
                                  &audioFormat, 
                                  sizeof(audioFormat));
    checkStatus(status);

    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(rioUnit, 
                                  kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, 
                                  kAudioUnitScope_Input, 
                                  kOutputBus, 
                                  &audioFormat, 
                                  sizeof(audioFormat));
    checkStatus(status);

    // Set input callback
    AURenderCallbackStruct callbackStruct;
    callbackStruct.inputProc = recordingCallback;
    callbackStruct.inputProcRefCon = (__bridge void*)self;

    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(rioUnit, 
                                  kAudioOutputUnitProperty_SetInputCallback, 
                                  kAudioUnitScope_Global, 
                                  kInputBus, 
                                  &callbackStruct, 
                                  sizeof(callbackStruct));
    checkStatus(status);


    // Disable buffer allocation for the recorder
    flag = 0;
    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(rioUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_ShouldAllocateBuffer, kAudioUnitScope_Global, kInputBus, &flag, sizeof(flag));


    // Initialise
    UInt32 category = kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord;
    status = AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof(category), &category);
    checkStatus(status);

    status = 0;
    status = AudioSessionSetActive(YES);
    checkStatus(status);

    status = AudioUnitInitialize(rioUnit);
    checkStatus(status);

    return self;
}

#pragma mark Recording Callback
static OSStatus recordingCallback(void *inRefCon, 
                                  AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags, 
                                  const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp, 
                                  UInt32 inBusNumber, 
                                  UInt32 inNumberFrames, 
                                  AudioBufferList *ioData) {

    AudioController *THIS = (__bridge AudioController*) inRefCon;

    THIS->bufferList.mNumberBuffers = 1;
    THIS->bufferList.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize = sizeof(SInt16)*inNumberFrames;
    THIS->bufferList.mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels = 1;
    THIS->bufferList.mBuffers[0].mData = (SInt16*) malloc(sizeof(SInt16)*inNumberFrames);

    OSStatus status;

    status = AudioUnitRender(THIS->rioUnit, 
                             ioActionFlags, 
                             inTimeStamp, 
                             inBusNumber, 
                             inNumberFrames, 
                             &(THIS->bufferList));
    checkStatus(status);

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [THIS.delegate  receivedAudioSamples:(SInt16*)THIS->bufferList.mBuffers[0].mData length:inNumberFrames];
    }); 

    return noErr;
}



-(void) startAudio
{
    OSStatus status = AudioOutputUnitStart(rioUnit);
    checkStatus(status);
    printf("Audio Initialized - sampleRate: %f\n", audioFormat.mSampleRate);
}

-(void) stopAudio
{
  OSStatus status = AudioSessionSetActive(NO);
  checkStatus(status);
}

@end
```

---

```
/*
 Copyright (c) Kevin P Murphy June 2012

 Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

 The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

 THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
 */


#import "PitchDetector.h"
#import <Accelerate/Accelerate.h>


@implementation PitchDetector
@synthesize lowBoundFrequency, hiBoundFrequency, sampleRate, delegate, running;

#pragma mark Initialize Methods


-(id) initWithSampleRate: (float) rate andDelegate: (id<PitchDetectorDelegate>) initDelegate {
    return [self initWithSampleRate:rate lowBoundFreq:40 hiBoundFreq:4500 andDelegate:initDelegate];
}

-(id) initWithSampleRate: (float) rate lowBoundFreq: (int) low hiBoundFreq: (int) hi andDelegate: (id<PitchDetectorDelegate>) initDelegate {
    self.lowBoundFrequency = low;
    self.hiBoundFrequency = hi;
    self.sampleRate = rate;
    self.delegate = initDelegate;

    bufferLength = self.sampleRate/self.lowBoundFrequency;    


    hann = (float*) malloc(sizeof(float)*bufferLength);
    vDSP_hann_window(hann, bufferLength, vDSP_HANN_NORM);

    sampleBuffer = (SInt16*) malloc(512);
    samplesInSampleBuffer = 0;

    result = (float*) malloc(sizeof(float)*bufferLength);

    return self;
}

#pragma  mark Insert Samples

- (void) addSamples:(SInt16 *)samples inNumberFrames:(int)frames {
    int newLength = frames;
    if(samplesInSampleBuffer>0) {
        newLength += samplesInSampleBuffer;
    }

    SInt16 *newBuffer = (SInt16*) malloc(sizeof(SInt16)*newLength);
    memcpy(newBuffer, sampleBuffer, samplesInSampleBuffer*sizeof(SInt16));
    memcpy(&newBuffer[samplesInSampleBuffer], samples, frames*sizeof(SInt16));

    free(sampleBuffer);
    sampleBuffer = newBuffer;
    samplesInSampleBuffer = newLength;

    if(samplesInSampleBuffer>(self.sampleRate/self.lowBoundFrequency)) {
        if(!self.running) {
            [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(performWithNumFrames:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:newLength]];
            self.running = YES;
        }
        samplesInSampleBuffer = 0;
    } else {
        //printf("NOT ENOUGH SAMPLES: %d\n", newLength);
    }
}


#pragma mark Perform Auto Correlation

-(void) performWithNumFrames: (NSNumber*) numFrames;
{
    int n = numFrames.intValue; 
    float freq = 0;

    SInt16 *samples = sampleBuffer;

    int returnIndex = 0;
    float sum;
    bool goingUp = false;
    float normalize = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
        sum = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j<n; j++) {
            sum += (samples[j]*samples[j+i])*hann[j];
        }
        if(i ==0 ) normalize = sum;
        result[i] = sum/normalize;
    }


    for(int i = 0; i<n-8; i++) {
        if(result[i]<0) {
            i+=2; // no peaks below 0, skip forward at a faster rate
        } else {
            if(result[i]>result[i-1] && goingUp == false && i >1) {

                //local min at i-1

                goingUp = true;

            } else if(goingUp == true && result[i]<result[i-1]) {

                //local max at i-1

                if(returnIndex==0 && result[i-1]>result[0]*0.95) {
                    returnIndex = i-1;
                    break; 
                    //############### NOTE ##################################
                    // My implemenation breaks out of this loop when it finds the first peak.
                    // This is (probably) the greatest source of error, so if you would like to
                    // improve this algorithm, start here. the next else if() will trigger on 
                    // future local maxima (if you first take out the break; above this paragraph)
                    //#######################################################
                } else if(result[i-1]>result[0]*0.85) {
                }
                goingUp = false;
            }       
        }
    }

    freq =self.sampleRate/interp(result[returnIndex-1], result[returnIndex], result[returnIndex+1], returnIndex);
    if(freq >= 27.5 && freq <= 4500.0) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [delegate updatedPitch:freq];
        }); 
    }
    self.running = NO;
}


float interp(float y1, float y2, float y3, int k);
float interp(float y1, float y2, float y3, int k) {

    float d, kp;
    d = (y3 - y1) / (2 * (2 * y2 - y1 - y3));
    //printf("%f = %d + %f\n", k+d, k, d);
    kp  =  k + d;
    return kp;
}
@end
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure what the best solution would be, but perhaps this project might give you some ideas: https://github.com/starzia/ClapIR

What the app basically does, is first allow the user to record background noise; afterwards the user is allowed to clap. The background noise is used in order to calculate decibel levels of a clap (I think).

Comment: Define a threshold in your callback for a minimum sample value -any value below which is considered 'noise' - and anything below that set to zero.